# Is it possible to add a border to an entire column and rows with Laravel Excel? using PHP variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, maatwebsite-excel

```
$range="A1:J10";

$sheet->setBorder($range);
```

but in this way, server give error

Comment: What is the error?
it works for me in my project.

Comment: Please attach error logs

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for your problem:

```
$range = "A1:J10";
$sheet->setBorder($range, 'thin');
```

Or you can use this:

```
$range = "A1:J10";
$sheet->cells($range, function($cells) {
      $cells->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin');
});
```